# GWT -Compilation Artifacts

Tags: gwt

I just have a general question as to how the GWT compiler implements java code in a project. Does the code in a compilation artifact originate from a single java file, a collection of java files, or both depending on how the implementation is made.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilation Artifacts can originate from a collection of java files